# Interesting behavior of compiler with namespaces

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, namespaces, argument-dependent-lookup

Assume the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace X
{
  class A{};

  void f(A a){}

  void g(int a){}
}

int main()
{
  X::A a;
  f(a);
  g(5);
}
```

When I compile the code, the following compile error occurs:

> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>   main.cpp: error: 'g' was not declared in this scope

So the function `f` is compiled perfectly, but `g` isn't. How? Both of them belong to the same namespace. Does the compiler deduce that function `f` belongs to the `X` namespace from the argument of type `X::A`? How does compiler behave in such cases?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This works for the function call expression:

```
f(a);
```

because the namespace that `X::A` belongs to is included in the lookup for the function `f` due to [argument dependent lookup(*ADL*)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), cppreference explains *ADL* as follows:

> Argument-dependent lookup, also known as ADL, or Koenig lookup, is the
>   set of rules for looking up the unqualified function names in
>   function-call expressions, including implicit function calls to
>   overloaded operators. These function names are looked up in the
>   namespaces of their arguments in addition to the scopes and namespaces
>   considered by the usual unqualified name lookup.
>
> Argument-dependent lookup makes it possible to use operators defined
>   in a different namespace

This is covered in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `3.4.2` *Argument-dependent name lookup*:

> When the postfix-expression in a **function call (5.2.2) is an unqualified-id, other namespaces not considered
>   during the usual unqualified lookup (3.4.1) may be searched,** and in those namespaces, namespace-scope
>   friend function or function template declarations (11.3) not otherwise visible may be found

and goes on to say:

> For each **argument type T in the function call, there is a set of zero or more associated namespaces** and a
>   set of zero or more associated classes to be considered. The sets of namespaces and classes is determined
>   entirely by the types of the function arguments (and the namespace of any template template argument).

and includes the following bullet:

> If T is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are: the class itself; the class of which it is a
>   member, if any; and its direct and indirect base classes. **Its associated namespaces are the namespaces
>   of which its associated classes are members**.[...]

and further down provides a similar example to your problem:

```
namespace NS {
  class T { };
  void f(T);
  void g(T, int);
}

NS::T parm;
void g(NS::T, float);

int main() {
  f(parm); // OK: calls NS::f
  extern void g(NS::T, float);
  g(parm, 1); // OK: calls g(NS::T, float)
}
```

The function call expression:

```
g(5);
```

does not work because *ADL* does not add any namespaces for arguments that are fundamental types.

Herb Sutter covers ADL in [Gotw #30](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/030.htm) and in [What's In a Class? - The Interface Principle](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm).

Comment: Does `extern` in the example affect anything?

Comment: @dyp ugh, thank you for pointing that out, I wish everyone was as observant when reading other peoples answers.

Comment: I'm always interested in reading your answers, since they're typically very comprehensive and you're using a broad range of sources. I just had some trouble understanding the first sentence at first glance (you know, the intro is often a simple abstract/overview).

Comment: @dyp C++ is my job and what I love doing, so writing comprehensive answers keeps me honest and learning. I don't always do a great job but I am happy to make improvements based on constructive feedback.

Comment: @0x499602D2 so the `extern` does not effect the result, `g` is implicitly `extern` but the local declaration of `g` does matter. I must have been really slow yesterday I figured out why it works pretty quickly this morning.

Answer (score 28):

```
X::A a;
f(a);
```

works because of **Argument-Dependent Lookup** (Also known as Koenig Lookup). `a` is an object of class `A` inside namespace `X`, when compiler searches a match-able function `f`, it will look into namespace `X` in this case.  See [Argument Dependent Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) for more information.

Comment: So this is why I see std:: getting pulled in when I thought I would need the prefix. Neat.

Answer (score 6):

When the code `f(a)`, the compiler finds the function `void f(A a){}` in the `namespace X` because of the [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (argument dependent lookup, also known as [Koenig](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/a-personal-note-about-argument-dependent/232901443) lookup).

`A` is declared in the namespace `X`, hence when the compiler needs to look up the definition of `f`, it includes possibilities from that namespace because the object `a` of type `A` is in that namespace (as declared `X::A a;`).

On the other hand, `int` is not declared in the `namespace X`, so the `namespace X` is not included in the lookup. Since no corresponding function for `f` is found, it fails to compile.

Comment: Argument dependent lookup