# Functions in namespace std accessible in global scope

Tags: c++, algorithm, include, std, using

Under some situations, it seems like I can access functions that should be in the std namespace without a `using` or `std::` qualifier. So far, I've only seen this occur with functions from the `algorithm` library.

In the following example, I expect `all_of()` to be in the std namespace, but this code compiles without error in VS2013 (Microsoft Compiler 18).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    const std::string text = "hey";
    std::cout << all_of(begin(text),end(text),islower);
    return 0;
}
```

Changing `std::cout` to `cout` without adding a `using namespace std` or `using std::cout` generates an "undeclared identifier" error as expected.

What's going on here?

Comment: Argument-dependent lookup?

Comment: Related? [Interesting behavior of compiler with namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976267/interesting-behavior-of-compiler-with-namespaces)

Comment: @Niall Not really a duplicate, I'd say. It is not immediately obvious that `std::string::const_iterator` is a class in namespace `std`.

Comment: A google search for "namespace std cout lookup" yields ADL anyway

Comment: @Marco-A Well sure, but I didn't know to use the keyword "lookup". ;)

Comment: @Niall Thanks for finding the related question

Comment: No problem. ADL is not a trivial subject, but knowing what this behaviour is now enables you to research it further and get a good handle on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably happens due to [Argument-Dependent Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup). The iterator returned by `begin(text)` and `end(text)` is probably a class defined in namespace `std` (or nested in a class in namespace `std`), which makes namespace `std` associated with it. Looking up unqualified names for function calls looks into associated namespaces, and finds `all_of` there.

By the way, this is exactly the same reason why calling `begin(text)` works, even though the function template `begin()` is defined in namespace `std`. `text` is a `std::basic_string`, so `std` is searched.