# Namespace-scoped template function becomes visible in another namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I've came accross a strange namespace scoping behavior (using g++ 4.8.2).
To explain the problem I've extracted a minimal code that reproduces this strange behavior:

```
namespace Weird {
  template <typename T>
    struct Rec
    {
      T val;
      Rec( T const& _val ) : val( _val ) {}
    };

  template <typename T>
    Rec<T>
    foo( Rec<T> const& r )
    {
      return Rec<T>( r.val * 2 );
    }

};

Weird::Rec<double>
bar( Weird::Rec<double> const& _input )
{
  return foo( _input );
}
```

In this code I would have expect G++ to complain about "foo" not being defined in the scope of "bar", which is not the case; the code just compiles fine.

So I'm a bit confused.
Is g++ wrong (namespace leak)? Or if not, according to which mechanism does "foo" becomes visible in "bar" ?

Comment: See also: [Interesting behavior of compiler with namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25976267/1708801) for more details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (ADL), also known as Koenig lookup.

In short, use of an operator or unadorned function call will find names in the enclosing namespaces of the operands or arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I now understand this is legal. Nevertheless, though it seems convenient, I'm pretty sure this can lead to obscure bugs. I would prefer being forced to prefix with Weird:: in this case.

Comment: @YvesLhuillier if there is any ambiguity the program will fail to compile.